# Azure activity function in durable function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am currently reading the documentation on Azure Activity functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions

I read across these lines

> The tasks involve checking the inventory, charging the customer, and
> creating a shipment. Each task would be a separate activity function.

My question is why create separate activity functions and not one function so that the durable function can simply call that function?

If we create separate functions, then the logic to manage the interactions between separate functions needs to reside in the durable function which is not always desired.

Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Because thats how they are designed. There is an orchestrator function, which calls other activity functions similar to a pipeline, in a stateful way. One of the reasons they are separate is that the orchestrator function can call whichever one when its required. Keeping them separate is a best-practice.

Comment: If you only need 1 activity function then there's no reason to use the durable function model. Just write the one function with a timer/http/storage/etc trigger.

Comment: As an aside, I would try to steer clear of durable functions if you're doing anything that "fans-out" as the scaling interface, in my experience, keeps those new activities in the same worker and it often has OOM crashes. I've had more success using timer triggers for my "orchestrator" function and storage queues for my "activity" functions. Unlike durable function activities, AZ will eagerly spin up new workers in response to the queue growing.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental unit of work in an orchestration of durable functions is an activity function. A unique task is orchestrated for each activity function within the process. Activity functions may run sequentially, concurrently, or in a hybrid fashion. Activity functions don't have any limitations on the type of work you can perform within them, in contrast to orchestrator functions. Network calls and CPU-intensive procedures are typically carried out by activity functions. Data can also be returned from an activity function to the orchestrator function. Each called activity function will be run at least once during the execution of an orchestration, according to the Durable Task Framework. The purpose of segregating activity functions is to divide the process into smaller, easier-to-manage tasks. This enables more effective planning.

***The purpose of segregating activity functions is to divide the process into smaller, easier-to-manage tasks. This makes it possible for the code to be easier to maintain and better organized. Better scalability and parallelism are also made possible. If distinct functions are created, the durable function must contain the logic to control interactions between the individual functions, which is not always preferred. However, adopting the Durable Functions extension for Azure Functions, which offers triggers and bindings for the Durable Functions extension, can help to mitigate this.***

[image]

**Reference:-**

[azure-docs/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview.md)

[azure-docs/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings.md)